# Django model with choices as foreign key fails

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class MapType (models.Model):
    SE = 1
    FE = 2

    typeChoices = (
        ( SE, "Some text"),
        ( FE, "another text")
    )

    mapType = models.CharField(choices=typeChoices,max_length="2")
```

This MapType model is used as foreign key in another one:

```
class MapForm (models.Model):
    # [...]
    mapType     = models.ForeignKey(MapType)
```

This is the view, where I'm trying to create a new MapForm entry:

```
        newMapForm = MapForm()
        # makes no difference, wether a new maptype object is created or not
        newMapType = MapType()

        newMapForm.mapParent = mapEntry
        newMapForm.mapType = newMapType.SE
        newMapForm.save()
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Cannot assign "1": "MapForm.mapType" must be a "MapType" instance.
```

Any idea, whats wrong here?

Comment: Is the field called `type` or `mapType`?

Comment: ah true! i Updated the question with the correct view and the new error message.

Comment: you need to create an instance of MapType. Did you create one?

Comment: Not explicitly. I updated the code in the view: creation of `newMapType` an used this object. but the error is stil the same

Comment: But `newMapForm.mapType` should be set to `newMapType` directly, not `newMapType.SE`.

Comment: ok it seems, that i did not understand the choice thing. i thought the .SE part is the way to go when setting the mapType to SE == "Some Text"

Answer (score 0):

You need to be passing the MapType instance. Now you are passing the integer value MapType.SE (1).

I think it chould be:
newMapType = MapType(mapType = MapType.SE)
newMapForm.mapType = newMapType

Also, since you are using int values as choises: You might as well make mapType into models.IntegerField. I think it works anyway, because int is easily converted to string, but there's no point to it.

mapType = models.IntegerField(choices=typeChoices)